# Как отправить несколько вложений с помощью messages.send | VK_API Python

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу бота на Python 3, хочу отправить сразу 2 фотографии, не понимаю, как это сделать. В документации написано "Медиавложения к личному сообщению, перечисленные через запятую. Каждое прикрепление представлено в формате: <owner_id>_<media_id>"

https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send

Пытался так
`"attachment": 'photo-184198941_457241390',  'photo-184198941_457241391'`

И вот так
`"attachment": ['photo-184198941_457241390',  'photo-184198941_457241391']`

И вот так
`"attachment": 'photo-184198941_457241390', "attachment": 'photo-184198941_457241391'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ссылке, которой вы дали чётко указано, как нужно передавать вложения. https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send

> Медиавложения к личному сообщению, перечисленные через запятую. Каждое
> прикрепление представлено в формате:
> <owner_id>_<media_id>

Вам необходимо:

```
"attachment": "<type><owner_id>_<media_id>,<type><owner_id>_<media_id>,<type><owner_id>_<media_id>"
```

Вроде раньше так не работало, сейчас проверил на своих алгоритмах, сделано именно так.

Но у вас проблема ещё в другом, вы зачем-то добавляете дефис `photo-184198941_457241390`, а нужно `photo184198941_457241390`

Comment: Я не понимаю. В других случаях у меня с дефисом всё работает (когда одно вложение), да и все ссылки на сайте построены через дефис. Убираю дефис и не работает, я думаю, он нужен. Попробовал вашим методом и не сработало, отправляется только одна фотография.


`"attachment": "photo-184198941_457241390, photo-184198941_457241391"`

Comment: Спасибо. всё сработало, просто я пробел после запятой по привычке поставил)

Comment: @TankCommander вообще дефис нужно убирать, судя по документации. Может вы версию старую используете.